# why does the application stops working when trying to get files from a folder?

Tags: uwp

The problem is that my application is something like "hanging" when it calls GetFilesAsync. In the code below, the folder was obtained using FolderPicker. And during debugging I can't reach foreach loop. What can I do?

```
public async void LoadFiles(AutoResetEvent waitForLoadComplete = null)
        {
            var files = await Folder.GetFilesAsync();
            foreach (var item in files)
            {
                //some stuff
            }
        }
```

The problem was solved by removing AutoResetEvent.WaitOne() frob the code below:

```
               AutoResetEvent waitForLoadComplete = new AutoResetEvent(false);
               LoadFiles(waitForLoadComplete);
               waitForLoadComplete.WaitOne();
```

Answer (score 0):

When Folder.GetFilesAsync() finishes, the continuation (the foreach loop) gets queued to be executed on the main UI thread. However, if you block the main thread using an event like that, it never has the chance to process the event and your app deadlocks.